# KXTJ9's Registers and Smartphone

Tags: android, accelerometer, smartphone

I have a Asus Zenfone 5 and your accelerometer is a Kionix KXTJ9. I want to access and change accelerometer's ODR.
How to access the KXTJ9's registers within Smartphone? It's possible?

KXTJ9 Datasheet - http://kionixfs.kionix.com/en/datasheet/KXTJ9-1007%20Specifications%20Rev%204.pdf